# Get data from external websites using HTML5/JS for Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom, curl

I am new to HTML5/JS for Android. I was wondering if there is a way of pulling data from external sources (Just like simple html dom OR curl for PHP). Am trying to build an app which need to pull the news from other sources (like BBC etc).
I'll appreciate any idea, link,any available open source project.

Big Thanks.

Comment: Portals usually offers their public news to developers with an API. For example, with BBC you can use [this](https://developer.bbc.co.uk/)

Comment: they ( BBC,etc ) can sue you for this, i guess.